# Identity Server 4: How to add Custom Claims only for UserInfoEndpoint and exclude them in AccessToken?

Tags: identityserver4, claims

We want to serve the large amount of data in the user claims from the UserInfoEndPoint but we don't want to embed those claims in AccessToken.

As far as I know, we can return the additional data from UserInfoEndPoint when we want to keep the AccessToken size small.  [Ref: Profile Service](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html)

So, I implemented the IProfileService as per following:

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();

        // Get data from Db
        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        claims.Add(new Claim("global_company_id", "88888888-D964-4A2B-8D56-B893A5BCD700"));
        //..... add series of additional claims

        context.IssuedClaims = claims;
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();

        context.IsActive = true;
    }
}
```

It returns the extended claims from the UserInfoEndpoint.  But, the problem is that these set of claims are also included in the Jwt Access Token too and it makes the token a lot bigger unnecessarily.

```
{
  "nbf": 1582236568,
  "exp": 1582236868,
  "iss": "https://localhost:44378",
  "aud": [
    "https://localhost:44378/resources",
    "testapi"
  ],
  "client_id": "testClientId",
  "sub": "78452916-D260-4219-927C-954F4E987E70",
  "auth_time": 1582236558,
  "idp": "local",
  "name": "ttcg",
  "global_company_id": "88888888-D964-4A2B-8D56-B893A5BCD700",
  //........ series of claims here
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "address",
    "roles",
    "country",
    "customClaims"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

Here is my Client Configuration in Identity Server Provider:

```
var clientUrl = "http://localhost:64177";
            return new Client
            {
                ClientName = "Test Web Application",
                ClientId = "testClientId",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                AllowOfflineAccess = false,
                RequireConsent = false,
                RedirectUris = new List<string>
                    {
                        $"{clientUrl}/signin-oidc"
                    },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
                    {
                        $"{clientUrl}/signout-callback-oidc"
                    },
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                        "t1_global_ids"
                    },
                ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("abc123".Sha256())
                    }
            };
```

Here is my MVC .Net Core Client configuration which connects to Identity Server

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                options.Authority = "http://identityserverUrl";
                options.ClientId = "testClientId";
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Scope.Add("CustomClaims"); // <-- here

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.ClientSecret = "abc123";
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

            });
```

Could you pls help me about it and let me know whether it's possible to hide these claims in token or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with this once and I found a solution, but it might be considered "hacky" -- it worked but I never used it in production, so use at your own risk.

The GetProfileDataAsync() method of your ProfileService gets called at various times -- when the JWT is created, when the UserEndpoint is hit, etc.  In this case, you DO NOT want your custom claims to be added when creating the JWT, so create a conditional that doesn't add them when the "Caller" is the JWT creation process (which is of type "ClaimsProviderAccessToken").

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
   if (context.Caller != IdentityServerConstants.ProfileDataCallers.ClaimsProviderAccessToken)
   {
      var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();

      // Get data from Db
      var claims = new List<Claim>();

      claims.Add(new Claim("global_company_id", "88888888-D964-4A2B-8D56-B893A5BCD700"));
      //..... add series of additional claims

      context.IssuedClaims = claims;
   }
}
```

With this, the JWT does not contain your custom claims, but if you hit the UserEndpoint it will return those user's claims as part of the JSON.